# Filter array of custom objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to filter an array of custom objects in swift to get back a subset of data that has properties I want to isolate. My code is as follows.

```
func generateSubset( dataPool : [CustomObject]) -> [CustomObject]? {

            let subsetData = dataPool.filter{(includeElement:CustomObject)-> Bool in
                return contains(includeElement.position, "TEACHER")
            }

        return subsetData
    }
```

My custom object is as follows:

```
   class CustomObject :  {
        var position : String?

        init(){
          position = ""
        }
    }
```

However the error Xcode throws me when trying to compile this code is:

```
Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type [CustomObject] -> Bool
```

I'm using Swift 1.2 and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 1.2, `filter` is a global function, so you can't say `dataPool.filter(...)`. (In Swift 2, this will work.)

Furthermore, `contains` can't be used with Strings like that. I would recommend using the `rangeOfString:` method from NSString:

```
let teachers = filter(dataPool) { // in Swift 2 this would be "dataPool.filter {"
    return $0.position!.rangeOfString("TEACHER") != nil
}
```