# Filtering UICollectionView depending on filter array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am having a problem that I can't find a good answer to by myself.

I have an array containing objects that contain information about companies. Based on this objects I create a collection view where I populate the items from the information inside those objects.

```
var suppliers = [Suppliers]()
```

Now I want to add buttons with specific filters. When pressed on one or more of those buttons the collection view should update with the filters applied.

Therefore I made a few buttons and when pressed I add them to an array containing all the filters.

```
var filters = [Category]()
```

After that I call a method that should do the filtering and update the collection view.

```
private func filter()
{
    if filters.count > 0 {
        suppliers.filter({ ($0.category!).contains(filters)})
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't comparison like that, according to xCode. How do I achieve this filtering correctly?

edit: See the structure of the object below.

```
struct Supplier : JSONJoy {

    var about: String?
    var category: Array<Category>?
    var logo: String?
    var name: String?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        name = decoder["name"].string
        logo = decoder["logo"].string
        about = decoder["about"].string
        if let ctgrys = decoder["category"].array {
            category = Array<Category>()
            for ctgryDecoder in ctgrys {
                category?.append(Category(ctgryDecoder))
            }
        }
}

struct Category : JSONJoy {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        id = decoder["id"].integer
        name = decoder["name"].string
    }

}
```

Comment: does your array contain 'custom object'? show the structure of data.

Comment: I added the custom objects structures @the_UB

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039714/filter-array-of-custom-objects-in-swift) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709723/filter-array-of-anyobject-in-swift)

Comment: How do you want to filter the suppliers? Do you want the `suppliers` with at **least one filter** listed in `filters`? Or all the supplier having **all the filters** listed in `filters`?

Answer (score 1):

1) `$0.category!` is `[Category]` type. And you have `[Category].contains` call which requires `(Category) throws -> Bool` parameter, but in your case it is `filters` variable with `[Category]` type

2) You never apply your filter result

This is possible implementation of your filtering, if I understand your needs correctly:

```
private func filter() -> [Supplier] {
    if filters.count > 0 {
        return suppliers.filter { supplier in
            return supplier.category?.contains { supplierCategory in
                return filters.contains {
                    return supplierCategory.id == $0.id
                }
            } ?? false
        }
    } else {
        return suppliers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to fix a couple of details that are going to make our lifes easier :)

### 1. Category becomes Equatable and Hashable

```
struct Category: JSONJoy, Equatable, Hashable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        id = decoder["id"].integer
        name = decoder["name"].string
    }
    var hashValue: Int { get { return id?.hashValue ?? 0 } }
}

func ==(left:Category, right:Category) -> Bool {
    return left.id == right.id && left.name == right.name
}
```

### 2. Supplier does not like an optional category property

```
struct Supplier: JSONJoy {

    var about: String?
    var category = [Category]() // <- I changed this
    var logo: String?
    var name: String?

    init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) {
        name = decoder["name"].string
        logo = decoder["logo"].string
        about = decoder["about"].string
        if let ctgrys = decoder["category"].array {
            category = Array<Category>()
            for ctgryDecoder in ctgrys {
                category.append(Category(ctgryDecoder))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 3. Now let't filter them all

You have your list of suppliers and your list of filters

```
var suppliers = [Supplier]()
var filters = [Category]()
```

Now I am not sure about how you want to filter `suppliers`.

However **IF** you want all the suppliers having **at least a filter** listed in `filters` then

```
let requiredFilters = Set(filters)
let supplierWithAtLeastOneRequiredFilter = suppliers.filter { !Set($0.category).intersect(requiredFilters).isEmpty }
```

On the other hand **IF** you want all the suppliers having **all the filters** listed in `filters` then

```
let requiredFilters = Set(filters)
let supplierWithEveryRequiredFilter = suppliers.filter { Set($0.category).isSupersetOf(filters) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `filtered` is the filtered `array` of `Supplier`. and `AllData` is the full array of `Supplier`. And you want to filter only items which contain the word `"ao"` at their `name` property.

```
  filtered  = AllData.filter {
                $0.name.rangeOfString("ao", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
            }
        if(filtered.count == 0){
           //No Results - 
        } else {
              //There are results - update the tableView data source accordingly
        }
```